# Change the Hosts files on both SQL nodes to show 127.0.0.1 LocalHost

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, xp-cmdshell

How to do this ?

Change the Hosts files on both SQL nodes to show 127.0.0.1 LocalHost

Comment: Insofar as this question relates to the discussion of http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41347/discussion-on-question-by-sqlboy-sql-query-failing-because-of-commented-part-of , I do not see how this is related to the issue. That and localhost usually defaults to 127.0.0.1 anyway, I thought...have you pinging `localhost`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosts file on a server is typically located at: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. In this location you will see several files, one of which is the Hosts file. Edit with caution.